# Best way to assign penalty in neural networks?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, supervised-learning

I have a directed weighted graph data structure where the weight between say Node A and Node B tells about the number of times a transition from Node A to Node B was taken.

The aim of the data structure is to identify the pattern of traveling between nodes.

For this, the weights are linearly incremented for each transition (Please tell me if there's a better way to increment it)

But, if a user goes out of way of his usual traveling path, a penalty to the most probable path and a reinforcement to the newly taken path must be assigned so that the weights are adjusted quickly according to the change in pattern. Thereby making the system more quick to self-learning.

What is the best way to assign this penalty/reinforcement? I could just randomly select to halve/double the weights but that would have no cited reason behind it and sound more like a whim.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather give a new path’s reward a higher value; maybe adding a bonus of the inverse of times travelled.

I would not suggest penalising the probable path. It’s not part of the state and not how RL mostly work. Rather consider eligibility traces.

On another note, rather than adjusting/tweaking the learning, considering improving your initialization of the states, that might be better; it appears by  your post that you are currently trying to apply background information about the data.